# bash code to run python file continuously

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

1. The python file in question collects data from API and the server is down once in a while so it stops running. to solve this, I've written this batch file that would keep running the file even if it encounters an error, so in few minutes it would be running as usual.

   :1

   python3 datacollection.py

   goto 1

Now, how do I achieve the same with bash file?

Note: I want to run the python file on AWS EC2 Ubuntu.

Comment: An endless loop can be done in bash using `while :`, or `while true`, depending on your taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to @Willian Pursell answer. You could run `screen` command on your AWS server, then run `while sleep 1; do python3 datacollection.py; done` in your newly created session. Finally detach to the session using `Ctrl` + `ad` keys. With that, you will be able to exit your session. Exit the server, the command will keep running on the background. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  But surely you mean `tmux`!  Not to start a flame war :)  Many terminal emulators would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. so far no problem. it's running just fine. thanks again.

Comment: @WilliamPursell indeed 笑. Cheers!

Comment: @Mantra I am happy to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of process manager e.g pm2 for this. It will be more stable than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
while sleep 1; do python3 datacollection.py; done
```

Don't forget the sleep, or you will be annoyed when it falls into a crash loop with `python3` aborting immediately.